# Number formatting in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have field value in oracle that needs to be manipulated as below for output

```
value*100
```

Example:

- if it is `172.24` to be shown as `17224.0`
- if it is `13.4567` to be shown as `1345.67`

Please suggest how this should be handled in **Oracle**. I tried  implementing it using case but that didn't work out.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
select to_char(value*100,'FM9999990.09') from data;
```

For example (using the `with` clause just to set up some test data):

```
with data as
 (select 13.4567 value from dual
 union all
 select 13.456 value from dual
 union all
 select 13.45 value from dual
 )
select to_char(value*100,'FM9999990.09') from data;

1345.67
1340.6
1300.0
```

Comment: Hi Tony - I tried this, it rounds off  my second example to 1345.60. My problem statement is if after multiplying number by 100 is whole number then append .0 else pick the value as is.

Comment: How to use with data in a select statement..didn't get your example

Comment: You can ignore the `with data as (...)` part, that was just to fake a table called "data".  The `select` is the important part.

Comment: Hi - I tried this, what it is doing is as follows- if number is 100.34 it is showing as is, 100.3 after multiplying by 100 adding one zero - 100.30 and if it is a whole number then 100.00

Comment: What I want is -   if after multiplying a number by 100 is 100.33 then it should remain as is, if it's 100.3 then also as is no extra zero to be padded and if it is a whole number then 100.0 convert into decimal number with one zero after decimal

Comment: Funny which comment got an uptick.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this-

```
SELECT (value*100) "New value" 
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Time to self-delete this answer - clearly you didn't understand the original poster's problem. (See the other answer and discussion, and even the original question which was already very clear.)